# Youtube embed loads with low resolution thumbnails and looks blurry

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-iframe-api, youtubeplayer

we are using `YouTube Player API` to embed youtube videos in our app and right now we are facing an issue where when the video is loaded and ready to play, it loads with low resolution thumbnails and because of that it looks blurry.

We found that this behavior appears randomly and sometimes it looks OK with good resolution, there are ways to set the video playback quality with player api but nothing regarding the thumbnail. Have searched most of the places but couldn't really find the solution for this.

Also note that this works fine in our android app but looks blurry in iPhone, as well as in safari browser in iPhone when we open our website.

Let us know if anyone has came across this issue before and any kind of help would be much appreciated.